# Sencha touch basic picker issue in simulator

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2.1

Adding a basic `Picker` to a container in main view works fine in chrome browser on desktop. (no JS errors as well). But the same fails in simulator (Android and iOS). Picker is initially hidden and rendered on a button tap. On simulator, Picker sheet renders without data though I configured data in component. Also, when I tap on `Cancel/Done` buttons, picker does not go away. `adb logcat` does not have any useful message for this behaviour.
Am using Sencha Cmd v4.0.4.84. What could cause such a behaviour and how to fix this?
MainView.js

```
var chooseStreamPicker = Ext.create('Ext.Picker', {
    itemid: 'chooseStream',
    hidden: true,
    useTitles: true,
    slots: [
        {
            name: 'stream',
            title: 'Choose your stream',
            data: [
                { text: 'Text1', value: 1 },
                { text: 'Text2', value: 2 }
            ]
        }
    ]
});

var mainViewButtonsContainer = {
    xtype: 'container',
    defaults: {
        width: 200,
        xtype: 'button',
        margin: 10
    },
    items: [
        {
            text: 'Choose your stream',
            ui: 'action',
            handler: function () {
                Ext.Viewport.add(chooseStreamPicker).show();
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'My Foo Section',
            itemId: "FooButton",
            ui: 'round',
            handler: function () {
                this.parent.onMainViewButtonTap(this);
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'My Bar section',
            itemId: "BarButton",
            iconAlign: 'right',
            ui: 'action',
            iconCls: 'compose',
            handler: function () {
                this.parent.onMainViewButtonTap(this);
            }
        },
    ],
    onMainViewButtonTap: function (btn) {
        var me = this,
            activeItem = me.getActiveItem();
        var pickerValue = chooseStreamPicker.getValue();
        if ( pickerValue ) {
            var stream = pickerValue.stream;
            me.parent.fireEvent('main', me, activeItem, btn);
        } else {
            Ext.Viewport.add(chooseStreamPicker).show();
        }
    }
}
//MainView
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'main',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar'
    ],
    controller: 'MainController',
    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox'
        },
        scrollable: true,
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        items: [
            {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                title: 'MyApp Title'
            },

            {
                docked: 'bottom',
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                layout: {
                    pack: 'center'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        title: 'Home',
                        iconCls: 'home'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'ContactUs',
                        iconCls: 'user'
                    }
                ]
            },
            { xtype: 'spacer' },
            mainViewButtonsContainer,
            { xtype: 'spacer' }
        ]
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the picker needs to be created in line. I got this working with below code:

```
var pickerConfig = {
    xtype: 'picker',
    itemId: 'chooseStream',
    useTitles: true,
    slots: [
        {
            name: 'stream',
            title: 'Choose your stream',
            data: [
                { text: 'Text1', value: 1 },
                { text: 'Text2', value: 2 }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Inside the handler, checked if the component already exists in DOM. If not create it first time.

```
items: [
        {
            text: 'Choose your stream',
            ui: 'action',
            handler: function () {
                var streamPicker = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#chooseStream')[0];
                if (! streamPicker ) { 
                   streamPicker = Ext.create('Ext.Picker', pickerConfig);
                }
                Ext.Viewport.add(streamPicker).show();
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'My Foo Section',
            itemId: "FooButton",
            ui: 'round',
            handler: function () {
                var streamPicker = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#chooseStream')[0];
                if (! streamPicker ) { 
                   streamPicker = Ext.create('Ext.Picker', pickerConfig);
                }
                if (streamPicker.getValue() && streamPicker.getValue().stream ) {
                    container.parent.fireEvent('main', container, activeItem, btn);
                } else {
                     Ext.Viewport.add(streamPicker).show();
                }
            }
        },
```